# Mock @AuthenticationPrincipal argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have spring-security-oauth2 application which is a ResourceServer. We have a custom `PrincipalExtractor` class that builds the custom Principal object. This custom Principal object do not extend `Principal` or `UserDetails`

```
class CustomUser{
//some custom fields
}

class CustomPrincipalExtractor implements PrincipalExtractor{
  @Override 
  public CustomUser extractPrincipal(Map<String, Object> map){
    return new CustomUser(map);
  }
}


class SomeController{
  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity(@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUser user){
     //able to get user object 
  }
}
```

The above code works fine. Now I want to test the controller, but not able to pass CustomUser instance.

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class SomeControllerTest{
   @Autowired
   private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void test(){
    mockMvc.perform(get(...).principal(CANNOT pass CustomUser as it does not implement Principal))
  }
}
```

I looked at some other solutions which asks to have custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` but not sure how configure autoconfigured MockMvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to implement some workaround to get this work.

Created a mock Filter that sets the Authentication object in SecurityContext. Following is the code

```
public class MockSpringSecurityFilter implements Filter {
  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
      .setAuthentication((Authentication) ((HttpServletRequest) req).getUserPrincipal());
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
  }
}
```

Within the test

```
@Before
public void setup() {
  mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
    .apply(springSecurity(new MockSpringSecurityFilter()))
    .build();
}

@Test
  public void test(){
    mockMvc.perform(get(...)
     .principal(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(new CustomUser(), null))...
  }
```

Comment: What is the definition of `springSecurity()`?

Comment: [Found it](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test.html) - `org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers#springSecurity()`